# Как в базе данных найти нужный текст, что бы в нем были нужные слова

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Мне надо каким либо образом в базе данных `sqlite3` найти такую строку, что бы в ней были нужные мне слова

`=` не подойдет, ей нужна лишь ровно такая подстрока

про `%` и `like` знаю, но если слов больше 1, то оно будет искать ровно такое, просто в любом месте

пример
ТЕКСТ: Привет как дела

и если я буду искать "как дела", то он найдет, но уже на "Привет дела" или "дела как" ничего не найдет, единственное до чего я сам догадался это разделить текст на отдельные слова с помощью `.split()` и искать индекс через вот такую функцию, которая после того, как кончаться все слова начнет выдавать 0 индекс

```
def num(self, n, k): # n количество слов(len), k нужно, что бы в запросе после того, как слова кончаться искать 0 индекс
    if n != 0: n -= 1
    return abs(n - k) if n >= k else 0
```

с помощью этого мой запрос выглядит так

```
cursor.execute(
        f"SELECT answer FROM ChatAnswer WHERE reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 0)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 1)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 2)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 3)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 4)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 5)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 6)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 7)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 8)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 9)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 10)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 11)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 12)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 13)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 14)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 15)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 16)]}%' and reference like '%{msg[num(len(msg), 17)]}%'")
```

`msg` = слова, которые я ищу в ТЕКСТЕ в БД

так я нахожу такой ответ, что бы в нем где бы то ни было были те слова, что я указал, но выглядит это так себе, находит максимум до 18 слов, да и я новичок и вероятно есть более хороший вариант, а не это чудо юдо

Comment: Возможно, тебе поможет оператор вхождения in. Например, "дела" in "привет, дела"

Comment: В подзапросе разделяешь запрос на уникальные слова, получаешь набор строк одно слово на строку. INNER JOIN данных по наличию подстроки. Группировка по строке данных, подсчёт количества строк, сравнение с количеством уникальных слов, вывод только при равенстве.

Comment: *так я нахожу такой ответ* Запрос на ввод "дела так дела" вернёт и "Дела так себе", что вряд ли правильно. Если это неправильно - то после парсинга на слова следует в рекурсивном запросе заменять 1-е вхождение слова на пробел и одновременно прибавлять единичку к полю-счётчику.

Comment: Тут больше вопрос в том, правильно ли я сделал создав для этого функцию? или был какой либо другой способ найти каждое слово по отдельности(но что бы по итогу все были в том тексте, что я нашел) в предложении с 13 словами, к примеру

Comment: inner join, я думаю, я не подойдет, у меня 1 800 00 строк и каждое так проверять долго, мой способ будет по быстрее